# print all nodes SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

It's my first xml parser script.
My code:

```
<?php
$xmlstring = "
<book>
    <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
    <note>
    <to>Tove1</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
</book>
";

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
foreach($xml->note as $note){
    echo $note["to"] . $note["from"] . $note["heading"] . $note["body"];
}
?>
```

i want to print `note` children. but this code doesn't print anything ..
Where is the problem?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`note` is a SimpleXMLObject. So you would need to pointer (arrow) notation not array (bracket) notation.

```
foreach($xml->note as $note){
    echo $note->to . $note->from . $note->heading . $note->body;
}
```